# Running Jasmine tests in Maven using headless Chromedriver

Tags: maven, jasmine, selenium-chromedriver, pom.xml, headless

We have downloaded (the latest windows) Chrome driver to our project and we are able to run Jasmine tests like this:

```
mvn -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe
```

But we are unsuccessful in setting up the above system property in pom.xml.
We tried `<argLine>,` `<jvmArguments>` & `<systemPropertyVariables>` options in the configuration sections of the below plugins:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.18.1</version>
<configuration>
    <jvmArguments>
        -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe
    </jvmArguments>
</configuration>
```

Another plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
<artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<configuration>
    <argLine>-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe
</configuration>

<executions>
    <execution>
    <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                    <webDriverClassName>org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver</webDriverClassName>
                    <webDriverCapabilities>
                        <capability>
                            <name>chromeOptions</name>
                            <value implementation="org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions" >
                                <args>
                                    <value>--headless</value>
                                    <value>--disable-gpu</value>
                                </args>
                            </value>
                        </capability>
                    </webDriverCapabilities>
            </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

We are not sure if we are configuring Chromedriver path in the wrong place. when ever we run just "`mvn`", we get the following error when it runs jasmine tests:

[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
[ERROR] at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:138)

Answer (score 0):

The surefire configuration portion should look like:

```
<configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <webdriver.chrome.driver>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe</webdriver.chrome.driver>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have tried this already but it does not work. I tried the above settings in the following plug ins:
    
`<plugin>
<groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
<artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>`

Comment: And in this plugin:

`<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.18.1</version>`

Comment: @user6586336 Edited my answer: try using explicit full path.

Comment: thanks for the help! But It hasn't solved my problem :-(

Comment: @user6586336 So in that case, the executable does not exist that that location. We would need more information from you, an actual [mcve], in order to be able to help you.